# BLE Advertisements changing in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm very new to android and BLE. Currently, I'm trying to Advertise a data packet which changes periodically in android trough BLE. I used the following code which was available in https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising.

```
BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = (new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder())
                .setLegacyMode(true) // True by default, but set here as a reminder.
                .setConnectable(false)
                .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                .build();
        AdvertiseData data = (new AdvertiseData.Builder()).setIncludeDeviceName(true).build();

        final AdvertisingSet[] currentAdvertisingSet = new AdvertisingSet[1];
        //final AdvertisingSet[] currentAdvertisingSet = {null};
        AdvertisingSetCallback callback = new AdvertisingSetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int txPower, int status) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onAdvertisingSetStarted(): txPower:" + txPower + " , status: "
                        + status);
                currentAdvertisingSet[0] = advertisingSet;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingDataSet(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int status) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onAdvertisingDataSet() :status:" + status);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanResponseDataSet(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int status) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onScanResponseDataSet(): status:" + status);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onAdvertisingSetStopped():");
            }
        };

        //start advertising
        advertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, data, null, null, null, callback);

        //change the advertising packet
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].setAdvertisingData(new AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(true).setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true).build());
```

But when I try to assign a new advertise data as the last line I get

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.AdvertisingSet.setAdvertisingData(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData)' on a null object reference
```

error and app closed with both **setLegacyMode** true and false.
But I already assigned **advertisingSet** in **public void onAdvertisingSetStarted** function.
What should I need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code shown causes a NullPointerException is because it is trying to access `currentAdvertisingSet[0]` before you have assigned a value to that array element.

When the code initializes it with `final AdvertisingSet[] currentAdvertisingSet = new AdvertisingSet[1];` then the contents of the array is initialized with each element set to null.  The code doesn't initialize `currentAdvertisingSet[0]` to a non-null value until the `AdvertisingSetCallback` executes.  This is asynchronous, and will happen in at some time *after* the call to `advertiser.startAdvertisingSet(...)`.

The problem is that this callback hasn't happened yet when the next line `currentAdvertisingSet[0].setAdvertisingData(...)` executes a few microseconds later.  When it executes, the `currentAdvertisingSet[0]` element has not yet been initialized -- it is still null.  That is why the code crashes.

To fix this, you must wait to use `currentAdvertisingSet[0]` until it has been initialized.  You can certainly add a check like `if (currentAdvertisingSet[0] != null)` to prevent the crash, but in the code shown this will never be true, so the code will never execute.

Ultimately, you will need to move the code that alters the advertising set so that it executes at a later time.  You could put this code inside the callback, but that might not make sense for your use case -- there is likely no point in starting advertising then immediately changing it to something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Even if the ```onAdvertisingSetStarted()``` function called, ```currentAdvertisingSet[0]``` not get assigned. I really appreciate If you can give some instructions to resolve the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think that is a true statement.   I suggest you set a breakpoint on this line `currentAdvertisingSet[0] = advertisingSet;` or add a debug line that prints its value. I suspect you will find that it does have a value.

Comment: The issue was occurred due to legacy mode was false in my configuration. I was able to put ```currentAdvertisingSet[0].setAdvertisingData(new AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(true).setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true).build());``` in to a separate thread and successfully changed the advertising data in runtime. Your Instructions and advice were really helpful for my task. Im really thankful for you help.